# How to type number in Japanese (Chinese number not Arabic number)

Tags: discussion

How to type Chinese numbers like 九 (for number 9), 二十 (for number 20) on computer keyboard?

Comment: The same way as you type any other kanji. If that doesn't answer your question then please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10:

Windows key > Settings > Time and language > Language > Add a Language > 日本語

From there it's pretty simple. Just click on "ENG" on the right side of the taskbar near the clock, and pick Japanese. Once you see the "あ," you can type romaji and it shows up as Japanese.

Comment: I have it already, what I am having trouble is the typing of 九, 二十... and other numbers as well. I haven't found a way to produce those word other than copying it from somewhere else

Comment: @petwho What exactly have you tried? I have no problem typing 九 or 二十. There I just did it. All you have to do is type out the number in romaji. 九 is typed as "kyuu." 二十 is typed as "nijuu." When you type in Japanese, a dropdown menu should come up showing you various kanji and kana. You might have to scroll down a bit to find the kanji you need, but it's there.

Comment: I can type 二十 as you suggested, but 二, 九, none of those characters showing up after I type *ni*, *kyuu* or *kxyuu* respectedly (and hit tab many times).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the IME, there are multiple ways of entering a number in kanji:

Example for Google Japanese IME (in Hiragana mode):

1. By its reading: `に`→二,　`きゅう`→九, `にじゅう`→二十
2. From Arabic number: `２`→二, `９`→九, `２０`→二十